# Excel VBA Run Time Error '424' object required

Tags: vba, lotus-notes

I am totally new in VBA and coding in general,
i want to attache a pdf (Print.pdf) to a specific field (alias_3) in a lotus notes database but i am getting the error 424.

Any suggestions what i am doing incorrectly?

```
Sub aa()
Dim alias_3 As String
Set notesface = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")


  Set makeup = Nothing
Set makeup = notesface.GetDatabase("C2S2/ConsolidatedContracts", "p_dir\bpcmrtuat.nsf")
 Set docu = makeup.GetDocumentByID("00002BE6")

Attachment1 = "C:\Users\Desktop\aloxa\Print.pdf" 
rtitem = docu.HasEmbedded
For Each test2 In docu.GetItemValue("alias_3")
    test = test2.HasEmbedded   ----> here i am getting the error





    Set EmbedObj1 = docu.alias_3.embedobject(1454, "attachment1", Attachment1, "")
    Exit For
Next test2
Set EmbedObj1 = test.embedobject(1454, "", Attachment1, "")
Set AttachME = test.CreateRichTextItem("attachment1")
docu.GetItemValue ("alias_3")
If Attachment1 <> "" Then
Set AttachME = docu.CreateRichTextItem("Attachment1")
Set EmbedObj1 = AttachME.embedobject(1454, "attachment1", Attachment, "")
On Error GoTo 0
End If
ExitSub:
End Sub
```

Comment: I want to put the attachment that i am refering (Prind.pdf)  to the field "alias_3"                            The form will be open and saved by me.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Lotus Note documentation](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/lotusscript/lotusscript.nsf/1efb1287fc7c27388525642e0074f2b6/3c567087099f80948525642e0075cddc?OpenDocument), `GetItemValue()` returns either a String, an array of String, or an array of Doubles, none of them having a `HasEmbedded` property.

Comment: Any suggestion how i can do it?

Answer (score 0):

Your codes mixes getting values from an item with attaching things to another item, etc.

First of all: Do you REALLY have a richtextitem called "alias_3" in the design of the form that your document is made of? Or is the name of the item "Attachment1" as in your second part of the code? Or is it a default mail database, then the name of the item would be "Body"?

Just replace "alias_3" in the following code with the appropriate itemname. The complete code can be reduced to these lines (I replaced the variable names, so that another developer KNOWS what you mean by using "defaults"):

```
Set ses = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")
Set db = ses.GetDatabase("C2S2/ConsolidatedContracts", "p_dir\bpcmrtuat.nsf")
Set doc = db.GetDocumentByID("00002BE6") '- This line is dangerous, because the noteid can change easily...
strAttachmentPath = "C:\Users\Desktop\aloxa\Print.pdf"
Set rtItem = doc.GetFirstItem( "alias_3" )
If not rtItem.HasEmbedded() then
  Call rtItem.embedobject(1454, "", strAttachmentPath , "")
Else
  '- what do you want to do, if there is already an embedded attachment?
End if
Call doc.Save( True, True, True )
```

Comment: Tank you very much for this,

Comment: Tank you very much for this, maybe alias_3 is not a  richtextitem? how i can check this? Also this is not mail but a database with fields that i am attaching pdf files in the below line i am getting error 438                              'If Not rtItem.HasEmbedded() Then '

Comment: To check what type an item is, you simply open the database in Lotus Designer and check it...

Comment: finally i did it with the below code                                                         `Sub test()

                 Dim richTextInput_10 As String


Dim workspace
Dim uidoc
Dim attachment1 As String

attachment1 = "C:\Users\Desktop\attachments\Print.pdf"


 

Set workspace = CreateObject("Notes.NotesUIWorkspace")
Set uidoc = workspace.CurrentDocument



Call uidoc.gotofield("richTextInput_10")
uidoc.editmode = True
Call uidoc.CreateObject("TestOpject", , attachment1)

Set workspace = Nothing
Set uidoc = Nothing

End Sub




`

Comment: Sorry, but this is NONSENSE. You create an embedded object... This is NOT an attachment... And why is the name of your richtextitem suddenly "richtextInput_10"? And this code will never work, if there is no document open in the notes client... But I understood: You don't want to make it right, but play... then go and play.

Comment: As i say i am really new to this, and i couldnt it make it work with the previous way and i find out that if i have the document open i can use this way , that's fine because except the attachments i need to add also some others details in this document.   The "richtextInput_10" is the filed id ( i was taking incorect name before).